# Complex function derivative.

Tags: complex-analysis

Spent 2 hours solving this, but still no results. Let's define
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac12 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right), \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac12 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right).
$$
Proof, that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 |f(z)|^p}{\partial z \partial  \overline{z}} = \frac{p^2}4 |f(z)|^{p-2}|f'(z)|^2.
$$
Made lots of calculations. Is it true, that
$$
\partial_z \partial_{\overline{z}} = \frac14 (\partial_{xx} + \partial_{yy})?
$$

Comment: Yes. $\partial_{z\,\overline{z}} = \dfrac14 (\partial_{xx} + \partial_{yy})$

Comment: I noticed that even if you got answers to most of your (currently) 11 questions, you never *accepted* an answer so far. In the case that you are not yet aware of that procedure, have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 2):

We can write $\lvert f(z) \rvert^p = \left(f(z)\overline{f(z)}\right)^{p/2}$, by the definition of the modulus. Now, if we define $\bar{f}(z) = \overline{f(\bar{z})}$, then $\overline{f(z)} = \bar{f}(\bar{z})$. In particular, $\bar{f}$ is analytic if and only if $f$ is (by expanding in a power series, for example). Now,
$$ \left(f(z)\bar{f}(\bar{z})\right)^{p/2} =  \exp{\left(\frac{p}{2}\log{\left(f(z)\bar{f}(\bar{z})\right)}\right)} $$
by definition. Doing the first derivative gives
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \exp{\left(\frac{p}{2}\log{\left(f(z)\bar{f}(\bar{z})\right)}\right)} = \frac{p}{2} \exp{\left(\frac{p}{2}\log{\left(f(z)\bar{f}(\bar{z})\right)}\right)} \frac{\partial_{\bar{z}} \bar{f}(\bar{z}) }{\bar{f}(\bar{z})}, $$
since the $f(z)$ is a constant with respect to $\bar{z}$.

The last term contains no $z$s, so we can ignore it for the $z$ derivative. Differentiating again, we have
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}} \exp{\left(\frac{p}{2}\log{\left(f(z)\bar{f}(\bar{z})\right)}\right)} = \frac{p^2}{4} \exp{\left(\frac{p}{2}\log{\left(f(z)\bar{f}(\bar{z})\right)}\right)} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\frac{\partial_{\bar{z}} \bar{f}(\bar{z}) }{\bar{f}(\bar{z})} $$
It is clear that we will get what we want if we can show that $\partial_{\bar{z}} \bar{f}(\bar{z}) =\overline{f'(z)}$. This becomes clear when we unwind $\bar{f}$:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} \overline{f(z)} = \overline{\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f(z)} = \overline{f'(z)}, $$
since it is easy to see from the definition that $ \overline{\partial_{z}}=\partial_{\bar{z}} $.

---

Indeed, $4\partial_z \partial_{\bar{z}} = \partial_x^2+\partial_y^2$ for twice-differentiable functions, since the mixed partial derivatives cancel in that case.

Comment: You're genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just derivate:
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_{z\,\overline{z}} |f|^p
&=& \partial_{z\,\overline{z}}\left(f^p\overline{f}^p \right)^\frac12\\
&=& \partial_{z}\left(\frac12\left(f^p\overline{f}^p \right)^{-\frac12} pf^p\overline{f}^{p-1} \frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}\right)\\
&=& \partial_{z}\left(\frac{p}{2}f^{\frac{p}{2}}\overline{f}^{(\frac{p}{2}-1)} \frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}\right)\\
&=& \frac{p}{2} \frac{p}{2} f^{\frac{p}{2}-1} \overline{f}^{(\frac{p}{2}-1)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial\overline{f}}{\partial\overline{z}}\\
&=& \frac{p^2}4 |f(z)|^{p-2}|f'(z)|^2
\end{eqnarray}